# php echo message to specific page

Tags: php, echo

I've been trying to make a very simple contact form but I can't figure out how to make the "successfuly sent" message to appear on the same page as my contact form (as in the same window as the contact div)

Here's the php code (and don't worry about security and stuff it's just a personal projet for learing)

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST ['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST ['last_name'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];
$to ="email@gmail.com";
$subject = "new message";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From:". $first_name . $last_name);
echo "message";

?>
```

so I want my "message" to appear above my contact form. Any ideas? Ty!

Comment: How is this not working? You need to do a better job of describing your problem.

Comment: You have to deal with it via JS.

Comment: and you need to explain how the above code relates to your form.

Comment: Not necessary JS, can be done with PHP only

Comment: @Nenad Panic, currently your code is like when you open the contact page, it will send empty email, you need to put atleast `if` and `isset` condition so email only send when value posted via form

Comment: Shehary is right, just put your message in the session and check for it after the form is submitted. Your current code will display the message every time you load the page.

Comment: Currently the code sends the message onto a blank page for me but I don't want that I want it to appear on the contact page.

Comment: @Shehary how do I do that or what would I need to change in current code?

Comment: @NenadPanic  `if(isset($_POST['email'])) { //put your code here}`

Comment: @Shehary Ok but message still appears on blank page instead of the contact window. How do I display the "message" in the contact window on my index page?

Comment: @NenadPanic you forget to mention the part that you are posting the form values to another page the answer below has the solution, just modify the header redirection and put `$_GET` code on index page and there is a typo mistake in answer its not `HET` it's `GET`

Comment: @Shehary so do i change the header to just : header('location:index.php?msg=you email has not been received.'); ?

and than copy the  <?php if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
         echo $_GET['msg'];
    }
    ?>

to index like that or?

Comment: @NenadPanic yes that's all

Comment: Great it worked. Ty for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $first_name = $_POST ['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST ['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST ['email'];
    $message = $_POST ['message'];
    $to ="email@gmail.com";
    $subject = "new message";

    if(mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From:". $first_name . $last_name)){
       //redirect to the same page sending msg GET variable
       header('location:this_page.php?msg=you email has been received.');          
    }else{
       //redirect to the same page sending msg GET variable
       header('location:this_page.php?msg=you email has not been received.');          

    }

    //check if msg id set then display
    if(isset($_HET['msg'])){
         echo $_GET['msg'];
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What does he need a second redirection for? He just wants to echo that the message was successfully sent. You could simply echo the message directly instead of that useless redirection.

Comment: @alamnaryab what do I add as the 'location:this_page.php?'. I want it to appear in my contact div. So the small window on my index page.

Comment: redirecting makes him able to display msg on the same page and also on another page if he want, which is common practice

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST ['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST ['last_name'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];
$to ="email@gmail.com";
$subject = "new message";
mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From:". $first_name . $last_name) or die(header('location:every_page.php?msg=error in send msg');
header('location:this_page.php?msg=you email has been received.');
```